# get the splitcontainer context in user control click event

Tags: c#, winforms

Sir,
      I have a split container in which in right panel i have a usercontrol.In the user control i have few buttons like view,new,edit etc.Bottom of that user control a form will open based on what link is clicked on the left side navigation pane. now when i click the user control's view button, i should open a new form below it. how to get the context of splitcontainer in the click event?also if i want to retrieve the form values to save in database when i click the save button in user control, how to do it?

Comment: Make a separate issue of the second question (about saving) and make sure to give a lot more context and code. One sentence is not going to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your button in the click event:

```
Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
```

To get the parent of your button (if it was SplitContainer, you'll have to use Parent property 3 times, because the first one will get you your UserControl, second - left panel of the SplitPanel, which doesn't have a Name property, third - your SplitPanel, and 4th, if you want, your form name)

```
string splitPanemName = clickedButton.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name;
```

...or you can just get whole SplitPanel object:

```
SplitPanel currentSplitPanel = (SplitPanel)clickedButton.Parent.Parent.Parent;
```

...or Form object:

```
Form currentSplitForm = (Form)clickedButton.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
```

To do this, you have to be sure of the composition of your Form, so you can get the right controls at the right place.

Answer (score 1):

A `Click` event has a sender parameter, which is the clicked button. You could use the name of the button to resolve which form should be opened.