# to get the textbox values of the form in user control in splitcontainer

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the splitcontainer context in user control click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593406/get-the-splitcontainer-context-in-user-control-click-event)

I have a split container in which right panel, i have a user control on top.I have a left panel which has navigation links.now if i click a link in left side, a form opens below user control.Now if i click view button in user control, a new form should open in right side of panel below user control. also if i have some values in textboxes in form below user control, when i click save button in user cotrol, i should be able to fetch those values in user control button click event.how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use public properties(value of textbox.text) in you user control, they will contains your values. Also you can create static class with dictionary values, something like a session in web.